# Google Play pre-launch reports - resource name

Tags: android, google-play

How I should provide id of EditText for filling credentials for pre-launch reports on Google Play (Beta/Alpha versions of the app)?
I tried
`@+id/editTextLogin`, `editTextLogin`, `R.id.editTextLogin` and always get description "wrong resource name".

What is correct schema for resource name there?

Comment: Have you figured it out - could you please provide a working example as I'm struggling with the same issue.

Comment: Hi, sorry but no. I haven't tested answer as I gave up on this way of testing. Please let me know if you find it solving this issue.

Comment: Hi guys! Any news ?

Answer (score 4):

As information icon says:

> The Android resource name of the text field within your app where the given username should be entered.

AND [Android Resources documentations](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html) says:

> `<resource name>` is either the resource filename without the extension or the **android:name** attribute **value** in the XML element (for simple values).

So in your case `editTextLogin` will go in that field.

---

I would like to share my case as it is quite different than normal sign-in:

It is quite similar to Google sign-in. I am asking for username first and after validating it, on next fragment I am showing his/her name and designation and asking for password.

For above scenario I used two fragments. In Username fragment I kept one `EditText` with resource name `username` and next `Button` with resource name `login` and in other fragment (Password fragment) I used `EditText` with resource name `password` and again one `Button` with resource name `login`.

And this is how I provided my credentials:
[image: Pre-launch credential screenshot]

Example **Username** field:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
    android:id="@+id/username"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Example **Password** field:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
    android:id="@+id/password"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPassword" />
```

Example **Login** button:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
    android:id="@+id/login"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp" />
```

**EDIT**

Reference of new Google Play Store console

[image]

Comment: Are you suggesting that we need to insert `android:name` into the XML of these `EditText`? As poster stated, he attempted to use `id`. Clearly, the "Pre-launch report " page is very strange, asking for "resource name" when we never usually name views in layout.

Comment: Perhaps you could have included the XML for one or more of the related views for clarity.

Comment: Yes, value of the android:id

Comment: Where do you get Android:Id ?

Comment: @GavinStevens in your login layout xml.

Comment: @Omkar What should we consider for a flutter app?

Comment: @PurvikRana I think that for flutter is enough with key property in textField> Ex:  key: const Key('username'),

Comment: Definitely would be willing to give it a try.